# Application logging for corda contracts

Tags: corda

Could you please give me some pointers about , how to add application logs inside a corda contracts .

There is a page in corda documentation  about logs , but it does not provide a right example .
https://docs.corda.net/node-administration.html?highlight=logs

Also could you please help to an idea how to print a debug statement on the shell console . 
This information will be super useful .

Thank you .

Answer (score 4):

You perform logging within a flow as follows:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public static class Initiator extends FlowLogic<Void> {
    @Suspendable
    @Override public Void call() {
        getLogger().info("Logging within a flow.");

        return null;
    }
}
```

In Kotlin, this becomes:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        logger.info("Logging within a flow.")
    }
}
```

Logging within contracts should only be performed for debugging purposes. In production, contract verification will occur within an SGX enclave where logging is disallowed. You perform logging within a contract as follows:

```
public class TemplateContract implements Contract {    
    @Override
    public void verify(LedgerTransaction tx) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(TemplateContract.class).info("Logging within a contract.");
    }
}
```

In Kotlin, you can also use the `loggerFor` extension function to perform logging within a contract:

```
open class TemplateContract : Contract {
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        loggerFor<TemplateContract>().info("Logging within a contract.")
    }
}
```

You cannot log to the node shell, as the shell is actually a remote process communicating with the node via RPC.